# SQL Server : Parent/Child - Find deepest Child with status failed

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table:

```
STEPID|RUN_ID|SERIAL |PARENT|STEPNAME                                  |STATUS
171730|  3101|0103107|171696|6.9 - Load Program YXZ                    |Failed
171740|  3101|0103107|171730|6.9.5 - Step Test. Program YXZ Error Code |Failed
171741|  3101|0103107|171730|6.9.6 - Step Test. Program YXZ - Part 1   |Failed
171742|  3101|0103107|171730|6.9.7 - Step Test. Program YXZ - Part 2   |Failed
171743|  3101|0103107|171730|6.9.8 - Step Test. Program YXZ - Part 3   |Failed
171744|  3101|0103107|171730|6.9.9 - Step Test. Program YXZ - Part 4   |Failed
171745|  3101|0103107|171730|6.9.10 - Step Test. Program YXZ - Part 5  |Failed
171785|  3102|0103107|171751|6.9 - Load Program YXZ                    |Failed
171788|  3102|0103107|171785|6.9.4 - Run Test - Monitor                |Failed
171789|  3102|0103107|171788|6.9.4.1 - Step Test. Program YXZ - Part 11|Failed
171790|  3102|0103107|171788|6.9.4.2 - Step Test. Program YXZ - Part 12|Failed
171791|  3102|0103107|171788|6.9.4.3 - Step Test. Program YXZ - Part 13|Failed
171792|  3102|0103107|171788|6.9.4.4 - Step Test. Program YXZ - Part 14|Failed
171793|  3102|0103107|171788|6.9.4.5 - Step Test. Program YXZ - Part 15|Failed
171794|  3102|0103107|171788|6.9.4.6 - Step Test. Program YXZ - Part 16|Failed
171795|  3102|0103107|171785|6.9.5 - Step Test. Program YXZ Error Code |Failed
171796|  3102|0103107|171785|6.9.6 - Step Test. Program YXZ - Part 1   |Failed
171797|  3102|0103107|171785|6.9.7 - Step Test. Program YXZ - Part 2   |Failed
171798|  3102|0103107|171785|6.9.8 - Step Test. Program YXZ - Part 3   |Failed
171799|  3102|0103107|171785|6.9.9 - Step Test. Program YXZ - Part 4   |Failed
171800|  3102|0103107|171785|6.9.10 - Step Test. Program YXZ - Part 5  |Failed
```

I have 2 unique RUN_ID's, for the same serial. Foreach RUN_ID, I need to find childs, on the deepest level, with the status failed. From the above table I would like to find:

```
STEPID|RUN_ID|SERIAL |PARENT|STEPNAME                                  |STATUS
171745|  3101|0103107|171730|6.9.10 - Step Test. Program YXZ - Part 5  |Failed
171794|  3102|0103107|171788|6.9.4.6 - Step Test. Program YXZ - Part 16|Failed
171800|  3102|0103107|171785|6.9.10 - Step Test. Program YXZ - Part 5  |Failed
```

The 6.9 could be a valid child, but because it has childs with the failed status, it needs to be excluded. I don't expect more levels than 4, like 6.9.4.6.

It is possible to solve this in pure SQL ? I have tried to substring the level hierarchy, and expose it as separate columns and do some group by / CTE, but I can't get my head around it.

```
STEPID|RUN_ID|SERIAL |PARENT|Level1|Level2|Level3|Level4|STATUS
171785|  3102|0103107|171751|     6|     9|  NULL|  NULL|Failed
171788|  3102|0103107|171785|     6|     9|     4|  NULL|Failed
171789|  3102|0103107|171788|     6|     9|     4|     1|Failed
171790|  3102|0103107|171788|     6|     9|     4|     2|Failed
```

Update #1: 
Anand asked if the stepname starts on a single digit. It does on the real table, but I have filtered that out in my current CTE, because an error can't occur on that level.

Update #2: 
A paste bin link for creation of the table (faking the CTE) and insert statements: http://pastebin.com/7JmP99KP

Comment: Is there any way you can expose this test data in the form of a script? It would be easier to work on the solution directly, rather than taking some time building the table structure and adding in the sample data.

Comment: Sure thing! Give me a minute or two.

Comment: Q: Can stepname start at 6 instead of 6.9?

Comment: May we see your current CTE? It appears that you want the _last_ deepest child with status "failed", i.e. not 6.9.4.1, .2, ..., but only .6, correct?

Comment: @HABO I need to rework the CTE a bit before I can post it only. Does my pastebin link help you enough? You are correct that I'm looking for the *last* child, on a given level, with the status failed. Excluding all previous siblings, and any parent in direct relation with the found child.

Comment: What if 6.9.10 succeeds? Does it need to return 6.9.9 since it is failed, or exclude the entire 6.9.x branch since the last one in that branch succeeded?

Comment: If 6.9.10 succeeds, but 6.9.9 is failed, then 6.9.9 should be displayed. Any deepest child with the status failed, must be displayed.

Comment: Will the parent always be marked as failed if one or more children failed?

Comment: The parent is always marked as failed when a chlid has failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It got a little long winded parsing out the child node as an integer without it ending up as copy/paste speghetti, but at least you can walk the CTE's one by one to understand how I'm getting there.

```
WITH
    StepWithTrimmedName AS
    (
        SELECT
            *,
            SUBSTRING(s.STEPNAME, 1, CHARINDEX(' - ', s.STEPNAME) - 1) AS TrimmedName
        FROM
            dbo.Temp_Steps s
    ),
    StepWithPeriod AS
    (
        SELECT
            *,
            CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(s.TrimmedName)) AS Period
        FROM
            StepWithTrimmedName s
    ),
    StepWithCharacterLength AS
    (
        SELECT
            *,
            CASE
                WHEN s.Period = 0 THEN 1
                ELSE s.Period - 1
            END AS CharacterLength
        FROM
            StepWithPeriod s
    ),
    StepWithStartPosition AS
    (
        SELECT
            *,
            LEN(s.TrimmedName) - s.CharacterLength + 1 AS StartPosition
        FROM
            StepWithCharacterLength s
    ),
    StepWithRowNumber AS
    (
        SELECT
            *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.PARENT ORDER BY
                CAST(SUBSTRING(s.TrimmedName, s.StartPosition, s.CharacterLength) AS INT) DESC) AS RowNum
        FROM
            StepWithStartPosition s
        WHERE
            s.[Status] = 'Failed'
    )
SELECT
    *
FROM
    StepWithRowNumber s
WHERE
    s.RowNum = 1 AND
    NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM
            StepWithRowNumber c
        WHERE
            c.PARENT = s.StepId
    )
ORDER BY
    S.SERIAL,
    s.RUN_ID,
    s.PARENT,
    s.RowNum;
```

Comment: Great stuff! First rewrite of your script seems to kill of my CTE, which is very nice! Applying the needed filters seems to work as well. Now I just need to make sure that the different scenarios are supported. Need to do some more digging :)

Comment: Me tests haven't been able to break your solution, so I have accepted your answer. You got some magic skills! :)